# How can I use different layouts with my ListView depending on data coming from the on-board SQLite database?

Tags: android, listview, simplecursoradapter

My android app has a simple chat function. The chats are stored in the on-board SQLite database. I am using a ListView with a SimpleCursorAdapter to display the chats. This is what I have:

```
public class Chat extends Fragment {
    private View rootView;

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState){
        rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.chat, container, false);
        return rootView;
    }

    @Override
    public void onViewCreated(View rootView, Bundle savedInstanceState){
        super.onViewCreated(rootView, savedInstanceState);
        displayChats();
    }

    public void displayChats(){
        DatabaseHelper databaseHelper = new DatabaseHelper(getActivity());
        Cursor chatCursor = databaseHelper.getChatsCursor();
        String[] fromColumns = {"messageInfo","messageText"};
        int toViews{R.id.message_info, R.id.message_text};
        SimpleCursorAdapter simpleCursorAdapter = new SimpleCursorAdapter(getContext(), R.layout.line_of_chat, chatCursor, fromColumns, toViews, 0);
        ListView listView = (ListView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.chat_text_display);
        listView.setAdapter(simpleCursorAdapter);
        databaseHelper.close();
    }
}
```

I have a chat model that has a boolean, named localFlag, as one of its fields. If the chat is sent from the device, localFlag is set as true (or 1), if the chat is received from external to the device, localFlag is set as false (or 0).

My SQL call:

```
public static final String GET_ALL_CHATS = "select _id, localFlag, messageText, messageInfo from ChatTable";

public Cursor getChatsCursor(){
    SQLiteDatabase sqliteDB = this.getReadableDatabase();
    return sqliteDB.rawQuery(GET_ALL_CHATS, null);
}
```

What I want to do is if the local flag is set, I would like to use this:

```
SimpleCursorAdapter simpleCursorAdapter = new SimpleCursorAdapter(getContext(), R.layout.outgoing_line_of_chat, chatCursor, fromColumns, toViews, 0);
```

and if the local flag is not set, I would like to use this:

```
SimpleCursorAdapter simpleCursorAdapter = new SimpleCursorAdapter(getContext(), R.layout.incoming_line_of_chat, chatCursor, fromColumns, toViews, 0);
```

Notice I want to use `R.layout.outgoing_line_of_chat` vs `R.layout.incoming_line_of_chat`.

How can I go about accomplishing this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [`getItemViewType()`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/Adapter.html#getItemViewType(int)) and [`getViewTypeCount()`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/Adapter.html#getViewTypeCount()) in your adapter to inform `ListView` that there are different row types being displayed, so that it can provide the proper view as the `convertView` argument to `getView()`. Refer to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24915547/1207921), and also to a video called [The World of ListView](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=wDBM6wVEO70) for a fuller explanation.

**EDIT**

You will have to subclass `SimpleCursorAdapter` (although you might want to subclass `CursorAdapter` instead) in order to override those methods.

---

Aside: you may want to consider using `RecyclerView` instead of `ListView`. The principle is the same, but with a `RecyclerView` adapter you only need to implement `getItemViewType()`.

Comment: The [link](http://stackoverflow.com/a/24915547/1207921) didn't really seem to apply to my situation. Thank you, though.

Comment: @P.Alston It applies exactly to your situation. Ignore the first paragraph and the rest of the answer describes exactly how to make your `ListView` show two different row types. The only difference is how you would implement `getItemViewType()`. In your case, you would check the value of `localFlag` at the specified position.

Comment: I have no idea where to override those two methods. I know it's not available in my Chat class.

Comment: I found [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12180724/inflate-layout-on-listitem-based-on-listitem-specific-variable) post with example code that also helped out.